# Getting the currently matched route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a waiting list page that can be accessed via following routes

```
example.com/waiting-list
example.com/waiting-list/success/:email
example.com/waiting-list/ref/:ref_code
```

In each case I need to display correct UI, hence need a way of checking what case/url the page is accessed from. I can't seem to be able and find this in docs :/ https://github.com/reactjs/react-router

Routes:

```
<Route path='/waiting-list' component={WaitingListPage} />
<Route path='/waiting-list/ref/:ref_code' component={WaitingListPage} />
<Route path='/waiting-list/success/:ref_code' component={WaitingListPage} />
```

Since all routes lead to the same component (`WaitingListPage`), and because the view will differ slightly depending on the matched route, I need to find out within the `WaitingListPage` component which of one the 3 routes were matched.

Comment: how does your routes file look like?

Comment: react-router is supposed to render the correct component by the URL, why do you need to deal with it?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question/problem. Can you show us your routes file?

Comment: @Chris edited the question, hopefully it makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: @omerts I need to check inside component that is accessed, what route it was accessed from

Comment: It's not quite clear, and your routes are conflicted each other. /waiting-list/success/:xxxx will match with /waiting-list/:xxxx

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo thank you for the note, I edited them to get rid of the issue

Comment: As a sidenote, you probably (I'd have to see your **entire** routing) can omit the leading `/` for each of your routes. E.g they should just be `waiting-list/success/:ref_code`

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo, actually `waiting-list/success/:xxxx` would not match with `/waiting-list/:xxxx` because `xxxx` will only match a string up to the next `/`. So the initial routing provided wasn't technically flawed, though perhaps not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine which Route you followed, you could just check the value of `this.props.route.path` inside your component. That will show the route that was matched.

[image: route path]

Another property you might find useful is `this.props.routeParams` which is an object with the values for each of the route parameters (in this case the value of `ref_code`).

---

If you, for some reason, would rather use the traditional javascript methods you could simply get the `path` portion of your current `URI`:

```
window.location.pathname
```

Though, you are likely to find a similar object under `this.location`, as it will too contain properties such as `pathname`, `basename`, etc.